# Perl Regex match

Tags: regex, perl, unit-testing

I want to match only words like "abcunit", "hedhdunit", "ewedfunit"  and get into array from a text file using regex. Can any one please tell how can I get only that word in line. So for I am using /(....unit)/g but the charcters before "unit" are varying. Can any one please tell perfect regex for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

unit : abcunit

unit : hedhdunit

unit : ewedfunit

unit : eedunit

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Hello Avinash, My expected output is abcunit, hedhdunit ewedfunit eedunit line by line in an array.

Comment: What does your data actually look like?

Comment: unit : abcunit
unit : hedhdunit
unit : ewedfunit
unit : eedunit

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you need.

```
my @matches = $str =~ /\b\w+unit\b/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
\b[a-z]+unit\b
```

[image: visual regex]

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  unit                     'unit'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: Hey Paul. it is matching both words cause both words have unit in comman. How can I get only second word. Like abcunit

Comment: Yeah I got it thanks paul.

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget that if an answer solves  your question satisfactorily, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/227183). ;-)

Comment: I would be glad to do that when I will have reputation 15+.